# check many to many field exists in parent class

Tags: django

this is my blog model

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    pricing_tier = models.ManyToManyField(Pricing, related_name='paid_blogs',
                                          verbose_name='Visibility', blank=True)
```

I want to create a notification with post save signal if pricing tier has free-trial slug exists, so I tried as follows

```
def blog_notify_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created and instance.pricing_tier.filter(slug='free-trial').exists():
        try:
            BlogNotification.objects.create()
        except:
            pass


post_save.connect(blog_notify_receiver, sender=Blog)
```

this doesn't work as it always gives none, the following print shows empty queryset, eventhough the data exists in the  pricing tier field

```
if created:
        print(instance.pricing_tier.all())
```

How I can check if data exixts in the pricing tier field which is a many to many field of a parent class

Comment: Did you add the pricing tier while creating the blog or after creating it?

Comment: while creating pricing tier also get added and it exist in the database,, but it shows none if i print out it as above

Comment: Just read about it. You cannot add a pricing tier while creating blogs. So when the post_save signal is called, the instance really has no pricing tier yet. I think what you need is `m2m_changed`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#m2m-changed

Comment: So you add a signal when a pricing tier is added for blog. That is when you can do the stuff in `blog_notify_receiver`